# You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId, for stripe metered usage

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement stripe metered usage but while creating checkout session its throwing error `You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId`

***C******ode to create checkout session***

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: 'subscription',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        { price: price_1234..... },
      ],
      success_url: `${domainURL}/myTeam?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${domainURL}/myTeam`,
    });
```

According to stripe

> For metered billing, do not pass quantity

Refrence Docs - https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#create-session

Can someone please suggest what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: According to the docs, Metered billing prices and tiered pricing are in beta for Checkout. Have you reached out to checkout-beta-metered@stripe.com to participate? For what it's worth, your code looks perfectly okay, and works on my end.

Comment: Yes just wrote a mail to them to add in their beta program. Any idea how much time it will take to approve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Stripe this is what I got. Hope this will help who all are trying to use metered with checkout.

[image]

PS-  After sending mail it got approved in 2 hours for my account.